# Fuzzy Searching a Column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, string-matching, fuzzy-search, fuzzy-comparison

Is there a way to search for a value in a dataframe column using `FuzzyWuzzy` or similar library?
I'm trying to find a value in one column that corresponds to the value in another while taking fuzzy matching into account. So

So for example, if I have **State Names** in one column and **State Codes** in another, how would I find the state code for Florida, which is FL while catering for abbreviations like "Flor"?

So in other words, I want to find a match for a State Name corresponding to "Flor" and get the corresponding State Code "FL".

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

If the abbreviations are all *prefixes*, you can use the `.startswith()` string method against either the short or long version of the state.

```py
>>> test_value = "Flor"
>>> test_value.upper().startswith("FL")
True
>>> "Florida".lower().startswith(test_value.lower())
True
```

However, if you have more complex abbreviations, [`difflib.get_close_matches`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#difflib.get_close_matches) will probably do what you want!

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import difflib
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"states": ("Florida", "Texas"), "st": ("FL", "TX")})
>>> df
    states  st
0  Florida  FL
1    Texas  TX
>>> difflib.get_close_matches("Flor", df["states"].to_list())
['Florida']
>>> difflib.get_close_matches("x", df["states"].to_list(), cutoff=0.2)
['Texas']
>>> df["st"][df.index[df["states"]=="Texas"]].iloc[0]
'TX'
```

You will probably want to try/except `IndexError` around reading the first member of the returned list from difflib and possibly tweak the cutoff to get less false matches with close states (perhaps offer all the states as *possibilities* to some user or require more letters for close states).

You may also see the best results combining the two; testing prefixes first before trying the fuzzy match.

Putting it all together

```py
def state_from_partial(test_text, df, col_fullnames, col_shortnames):
    if len(test_text) < 2:
        raise ValueError("must have at least 2 characters")

    # if there's exactly two characters, try to directly match short name
    if len(test_text) == 2 and test_text.upper() in df[col_shortnames]:
        return test_text.upper()

    states = df[col_fullnames].to_list()
    match = None
    # this will definitely fail at least for states starting with M or New
    #for state in states:
    #    if state.lower().startswith(test_text.lower())
    #        match = state
    #        break  # leave loop and prepare to find the prefix

    if not match:
        try:  # see if there's a fuzzy match
            match = difflib.get_close_matches(test_text, states)[0]  # cutoff=0.6
        except IndexError:
            pass  # consider matching against a list of problematic states with different cutoff

    if match:
        return df[col_shortnames][df.index[df[col_fullnames]==match]].iloc[0]

    raise ValueError("couldn't find a state matching partial: {}".format(test_text))
```

Beware of states which start with 'New' or 'M' (and probably others), which are all pretty close and will probably want special handling. Testing will do wonders here.